# How do I use OpenCV MatchTemplate?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm attempting to find an image in another.

```
im = cv.LoadImage('1.png', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
    tmp = cv.LoadImage('e1.png', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)
    w,h = cv.GetSize(im)
    W,H = cv.GetSize(tmp)
    width = w-W+1
    height = h-H+1
    result = cv.CreateImage((width, height), 32, 1)
    cv.MatchTemplate(im, tmp, result, cv.CV_TM_SQDIFF)
    print result
```

When I run this, everything executes just fine, no errors get thrown. But I'm unsure what to do from here. The doc says that `result` stores "A map of comparison results". I tried printing it, but it gives me width, height, and step.

How do I use this information to find whether or not one image is in another/where it is located?

Comment: So you don't struggle with OpenCV as much, try SimpleCV. It's a wrapper around the OpenCV modules that makes them easy to use: http://simplecv.org/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MatchTemplate` returns a similarity map and not a location.
You can then use this map to find a location.

If you are only looking for a single match you could do something like this to get a location:

```
minVal,maxVal,minLoc,maxLoc = cv.MinMaxLoc(result)
```

Then `minLoc` has the location of the best match and `minVal` describes how well the template fits. You need to come up with a threshold for `minVal` to determine whether you consider this result a match or not.

If you are looking for more than one match per image you need to use algorithms like non-maximum supression.

Comment: So if I was using a method that records the best match at maxLoc I would look at maxVal?

Answer (score 13):

This might work for you! :)

```
def FindSubImage(im1, im2):
    needle = cv2.imread(im1)
    haystack = cv2.imread(im2)

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(needle,haystack,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    y,x = np.unravel_index(result.argmax(), result.shape)
    return x,y
```

`CCOEFF_NORMED` is just one of many comparison methoeds.
See: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html
for full list.

Not sure if this is the best method, but is fast, and works just fine for me! :)

Comment: Note that this will always return x, y irregardless of whether the template image is actually present, I recommend using a threshold instead.