# Multi-Scale template Matching doesn't work right

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, template-matching

I have done multi-scale template matching in real-time from looking at [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv). When the template appears in the frame, it detects it and drawing a bounding box around it which means it works fine. **But when there is no template in the frame also, it detects somewhere and drawing the bounding box**. I'll mention the code and the error that I recognized.

```
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils


def main():

    template1 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Manthika\\Desktop\\opencvtest\\template.jpg")
    template1 = cv2.cvtColor(template1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template1 = cv2.Canny(template1, 50, 200)
    template = imutils.resize(template1, width=60)
    (tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow("Template", template)

    windowName = "Something"
    cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    else:
        ret = False

    # loop over the frames to find the template
    while ret:
        # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
        # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        found = None

        # loop over the scales of the image
        for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
            # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
            # of the ratio of the resizing
            resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
            r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

            # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
            # from the loop
            if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
                print("frame is smaller than the template")
                break

            # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
            # matching to find the template in the image
            edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
            (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

            # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then update
            # the bookkeeping variable
            if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
                found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

            # unpack the bookkeeping variable and compute the (x, y) coordinates
            # of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
        # print(found)
        if found is None:
            # just show only the frames if the template is not detected
            cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)
            print("No template is found")
        else:
            (_, maxLoc, r) = found
            (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
            (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))
            print(startX, startY, endX, endY)

            # draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think the problem is in this two lines,

```
if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
                found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)
```

found variable always updates with a value even if it is none. I'm new to computer vision so please be kind and help me to solve this problem. And also kindly let me know if I need to mention anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [How do I use OpenCV MatchTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709631/how-do-i-use-opencv-matchtemplate):

In your code, you have `(_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)`, where it should be `minVal,maxVal,minLoc,maxLoc = cv.MinMaxLoc(result)`, and you need to set a threshold of `minVal` to filter unmatched results.

Example:

```
# loop over the scales of the image
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
    # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
    # of the ratio of the resizing
    resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
    r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

    # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
    # from the loop
    if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
        break

    # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
    # matching to find the template in the image
    edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    (minVal, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then ipdate
    # the bookkeeping variable
    if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
        found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

# unpack the bookkeeping varaible and compute the (x, y) coordinates
# of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
(maxVal, maxLoc, r) = found
# Threshold setting, this 11195548 value is tested by some random images
threshold = 11195548
if maxVal > threshold:
    print("match found")
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))

    # draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
else:
    print("no match found")
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The function `cv2.MinMaxLoc` finds the minimum and maximum element values and their positions from the similarity map of  `cv2.matchTemplate`, where maxLoc tells you where the upper left corner of the matched area is and maxVal tells you how well the match is. The code you posted would draw a bounding box for every image because `found` is always updated. However, if you could compare maxVal against a threshold before drawing the box, you would remove the false positive match images.

Comment: Just did. BTW, this method is computationally expensive because it needs to scale the image or template many times. Have you considered SIFT where SI means scale-invariant?

Comment: You mean feature matching right? I am still learning it and would be my next step for the same implementation. Thank you so much:) You did a great help. And if any good articles regarding feature matching, please share. Cheers!