# opencv and old games graphics python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am trying to match the following image

[image: original]

With the following templates, using `cv2.matchTemplate`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
#elementachercher = path to template png file
#screenascanner = path to global picture where to find template


import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import imutils

def tryfoundobject(elementachercher, screenascanner):
    img_rgb = cv2.imread(screenascanner)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.imread(elementachercher,0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
        if pt != None:
            print(elementachercher+" matched")
            break
        else:
            continue
    cv2.imwrite(elementachercher,img_rgb)
    
  tryfoundobject("/home/noway/template.png", "/home/noway/mypicture.png")
```

But no matches are found.

What am I doing wrong?
1 screen is what result i want, the second screen is what i got after script

[image: What i want after succefully script]

[image: what result i got]

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting and not getting

Comment: i m trying to use matchtemplate on the big picture, the small picture are my template for get template coordinates, X, Y of them 

but opencv never match my template on the main picture

Comment: what *does* happen? edit the question please to show `res` (normalize to [0,255] first), then show `loc`.

Comment: Could this just be an indentation error?

Comment: i edited my post for show what im trying to do with screen, what i want, and what i get

Comment: Please reply to my previous comment.

Comment: no indentation error, my script works fine but result is not what im trying to do
maybe i make a mistake during my workflow with opencv

Comment: what does happen? edit the question please to show res (normalize to [0,255] first), then show loc

Comment: ` normalizedImg = cv2.normalize(img_rgb,  res, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    cv2.imshow('dst_rt', normalizedImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

nothing change, i got exacly same picture as the last picture in my post,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232766/discussion-between-veilleurtrytofix-and-gulzar).

Answer (score 0):

Following [the chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232766/discussion-between-veilleurtrytofix-and-gulzar)

```
res_normed = (res - np.min(res)) / (np.max(res) - np.min(res))
res_uint = np.array(res_normed * 255, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("res_uint ", res_uint)
```

res looks like this

[image]

You have to look for local maxima on this image to get the coordinates of matches.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709631/how-do-i-use-opencv-matchtemplate/9716558#9716558) for a very simple POC and to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111711/get-coordinates-of-local-maxima-in-2d-array-above-certain-value/9113227#9113227) for the full solution.